# no filter named 'localtime'

Tags: python, django, timezone

I am using localtime template filter to convert UTC to localtime but I am getting this error.`

```
    <td>
        {{ test.created_at|localtime }}
    </td>`
```

but I am getting Template Assertion error. created_at is stored in utc in database.

In setting.py

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/ did you registered your custom template filter?

Comment: Seems there is no default one with name localtime, there are date and time